# Forms submit works on locale machine but doesn't work on hosting

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('.basic-cart-add-to-cart-link').click(function(){
      var unique = removeDuplicates(idArr);
      var speed = 3000;
      for(var i = 1; i <= unique.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(y) {
          var selector = 'form#basic-cart-add-to-cart-quantity-form-'+y;
          $(selector).submit();
        }, speed*i, unique[i-1]);
      }
    });
  });

  for(var i = 0; i < idArr.length; i++) {   
    $('form#basic-cart-add-to-cart-quantity-form-'+idArr[i]).submit(function(e){
      console.log('preventDefault: form#basic-cart-add-to-cart-quantity-form-'+idArr[i]);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
```

This part of code submits multiple forms. I have one button and many forms. When I click on the button, I submit all the forms which were marked and add all products to the order cart. `idArr` is array of form IDs.

It works perfectly on my local machine, but when I tried this code on hosting only the first form from `idArr` was submitted. In the order cart I have only one product, but on my locale machine I have all products.

What can be the problem?

Comment: try debugging. Hard to tell from this part. This looks ok. Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your code. It will help others to understand your issue better.

Comment: `i` inside submit handler would always be the last as i can see your code BUT it is completly different issue than the one you are describing

Comment: @A. Wolff, I debugging this part of code on locale machine and on hosting. On locale machine I have all ids and on hosting I have only the first id.